# Need help installing pycaret on MacOS in jupyterhub

Tags: conda, lightgbm, pycaret

I can pip install pycaret fine, but when I run setup() i get thrown an error that indicates lightgbm was not installed correctly:

```
setup(data=mmm[features + [target]],target=target, session_id=2)

ImportError: cannot import name 'is_dtype_sparse' from 'lightgbm.compat' (/Users/nickdimmitt/opt/anaconda3/envs/pga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lightgbm/compat.py)`
```

I have tried installing lightgbm with pip and conda seperately, no luck. Also have tried to edit the source code for lightgbm so it isn't dependet on 'is_dtype_sparse' but there has to be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. As one solution, you can try doing the same with the Google Colab IDE.
2. As another solution, firstly create a virtual environment, and then do the installations.

.

```
# create a conda environment

conda create --name yourenvname python=3.6

# activate conda environment

conda activate yourenvname

# install pycaret

pip install pycaret

# create notebook kernel connected with the conda environment

python -m ipykernel install --user --name yourenvname --display-name "display-name"
```

Here is a related link: [PyCaret Issue](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/999)